# Two approaches to delete multiple rows from SQLite

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I've tried two different approaches to delete multiple rows from database. They seems identital for me, but behaviour is different:

#1 Works as expected, delete rows with specified ids

```
public void deleteCycles(ArrayList<Long> ids) {
    String idsString = TextUtils.join(",", ids.toArray());
    db.execSQL("delete from cycles where _id IN (" + idsString + ");");
}
```

#2 Delete one row (list ids.size == 1) or nothing (size != 1)

```
public void deleteCycles(ArrayList<Long> ids) {
    String idsString = TextUtils.join(",", ids.toArray());
    db.delete(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_CYCLES, "_id IN (?)", new String[]{idsString});
}
```

Can somebody explain, where is the difference? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `?` means exactly 1 parameter ... with size != 1 it acts like `DELETE FROM CYCLES WHERE _id IN ('here is idsString.toString()')`

Comment: So in case of deleting multiple you need to make sure you create a comma separated ids list and then assign to idsString and then pass as argument value to db.execSQL

Comment: Selvin: Thank you, It makes sense, but when I use `TextUtils.join("','", ids.toArray())` what should produce e.g. "2','3", It doesn't work too.

Comment: you should generate as 2,3,.... and not "2','3".

Comment: @skywall using `?` will escape `'` inside your string .... it will be something like `IN ('2'',''3')` ... if you wana use delete form you should generate where with somthing like `_id IN (?,? ... as many ? as ids lenght ... ?)`

Comment: @Selvin Thanks, It was my thought too.

Answer (score -1):

for(int i = 0 ; i < (Your array list).lenght;i++)
    {

```
db.delete(mytablename,"Paragraph ='"+(Your array list)[i]+"'",null);
}
```